# ThreadStatic Modified with Static C#

Tags: c#, static, thread-static

I have some code where I use a thread static object in C#.

```
[ThreadStatic]
private DataContext connection
```

I was wondering, in this case, what if any change would I get if I put the static modifier on the thread static context?

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static DataContext connection
```

With the first would there be one copy of the context per instance per thread, with the other only one copy per thread?

Comment: +1 for good question.  I'd never thought of this.

Answer (score 58, accepted):

The `ThreadStaticAttribute` is only designed to be used on static variables, as [the documentation points out](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute). If you use it on an instance variable, I suspect it will do precisely nothing.

Comment: Anyone aware of any documentation that describes the official policy on what it's supposed to do? If it is not supposed to be used in this way shouldn't it cause a compile error, or can attributes not cause compile errors?

Comment: It would be great if it were a compiler error, because I've just spent a couple of hours tracking a mysterious threading-related bug, which turned out to be due to [ThreadStatic] being used on an instance field and thus having no effect...

Comment: Just remember though, the ThreadPool shares threads (and ThreadStatic) across several tasks.  You want to make sure the parallel task you are running is not running in a thread from the ThreadPool.

Answer (score 9):

In the first case it would probably be ignored, whereas in the second case you are correct, one instance per thread.

Answer (score 6):

In Microsoft Docs, [it says](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threadstaticattribute):

> Indicates that the value of a **static** field is unique for each thread.

So I guess your first case is incorrect. The attribute will probably be ignored.