# Question regarding behavior of static variables within multiple instances of single executable

Tags: c#

When a single application is executed multiple times in parallel, will statically-declared variables in that program be allocated on a single thread or duplicated among mutliple threads?

Comment: " same program is being executed in parallel" - one exe instance with multiple threads? or multiple exe instances each with one main thread (that touches these variables)? it matters

Comment: Static variables are shared, [unless](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5227676/11683)

Comment: @GSerg within the same exe

Comment: Hi - I was hoping to rephrase your question in a way that might more clearly refine what you're asking and induce helpful answers. I hope my edits reflect a correct interpretation of your question and you receive the help you need. Have a great day!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have a case where a same program is being executed in parallel,

If you mean you have multiple *instances* of the program being executed (i.e. different processes; i.e. you are launching `foo.exe` multiple times), then they are entirely independent.

If you mean you have one instance of the program, which internally uses parallel threads via any mechanism: then they are entirely shared... usually.

The normal scope of a `static` field is: the app-domain. Almost always, this means: the process.

If your `static` fields are immutable (including any sub-contents of them), then: it really won't matter much; they might as well share that readonly immutable state, for efficiency. But it you are *mutating* the values (including mutating any sub-contents), then it gets *really* messy. Frankly, if a static field is non-trivially mutated in any way (other than initial setup), it probably shouldn't be a static field.

However! There is also `[ThreadStatic]`. If a `static` field is marked as `[ThreadStatic]`, then the scope is per-thread. This is ... not a recommendation. In particular, it doesn't work with `async` / `await` at all, as you're not really in control of which thread you continue on - this means you could inadvertently switch between logical states, *without realizing*. Frankly, in this scenario, my recommendation would be to create an *object* that represents the per-thread or per-work-item state, and let each thread use that (perhaps the worker method could be an instance method on the same state object). This is very simple to grok, and makes debugging and refactoring much simpler.

Answer (score 0):

Operating system runs proceses with separated memory. So if you use separated processes, then you have different static variables. In same process static variable is alocated once for all threads.

Read about IPC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication